# Spark table joins - Resource allocation issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am stuck while working with hive tables using spark cluster (Yarn is in placed). I have some 7 tables which I need to join and then replace some null values and writing back the result to Hive final DF.

I use spark SQL (Scala) ,creating 6 different data frame first. and then join all the dataframes and writing back the result to hive table.

After five minutes my code throws below error, which I know is due to not setting my resource allocation properly.

```
19/10/13 06:46:53 ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from /100.66.0.1:36467 is closed
19/10/13 06:46:53 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 401 on aaaa-bd10.pq.internal.myfove.com: Container container_e33_1570683426425_4555_01_000414 exited from explicit termination request.
19/10/13 06:47:02 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 391 on aaaa-bd10.pq.internal.myfove.com: Container marked as failed: container_e33_1570683426425_4555_01_000403 on host: aaaa-bd10.pq.internal.myfove.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

My hardware specification

```
HostName    Memory in GB    CPU Memory for Yarn CPU For Yarn
Node 1      126             32  90               26
Node 2      126             32  90               26
Node 3      126             32  90               26
Node 4      126             32  90               26
```

How to set below variables properly, so that my code doesn't throw an error (container marked as failed - killed by request 143)?

I am trying different configuration, but nothing helped yet.

```
val spark = (SparkSession.builder
             .appName("Final Table")
             .config("spark.driver.memory", "5g") 
             .config("spark.executor.memory", "15g") 
             .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors","6")
             .config("spark.executor.cores", "5")
             .enableHiveSupport()
             .getOrCreate())



DF1 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_1") //1.4 million records and 10 var 
DF2 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_2") //1.4 million records and 3000 
DF3 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_3") //1.4 million records and 300 
DF4 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_4") //1.4 million records and 600 
DF5 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_5") //1.4 million records and 150 
DF6 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_6") //1.4 million records and 2 
DF7 = spark.sqk("Select * from table_7") //1.4 million records and 12 


val joinDF1 = df1.join(df2, df1("number") === df2("number"), "left_outer").drop(df2("number")) 
val joinDF2 = joinDF1.join(df3,joinDF1("number") === df3("number"), "left_outer").drop(df3("number")) 
val joinDF3 = joinDF2.join(df4,joinDF2("number") === df4("number"), "left_outer").drop(df4("number")) 
val joinDF4 = joinDF3.join(df5,joinDF3("number") === df5("number"), "left_outer").drop(df5("number")) 
val joinDF5 = joinDF4.join(df6,joinDF4("number") === df6("number"), "left_outer").drop(df6("number")).drop("Dt") 
val joinDF6 = joinDF5.join(df7,joinDF5("number") === df7("number"), "left_outer").drop(df7("number")).drop("Dt") 
joinDF6.createOrReplaceTempView("joinDF6")

spark.sql("create table hive table as select * from joinDF6")
```

Comment: Use the [edit] button and code formatting buttons in your question. Don't post code in comments and definitely don't post answers if they are not answers

Comment: How many tasks are generated at the last stage? Also, why do you limit the number of executors to 6?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs in Ambari if you are using Ambari. If not, try to find out this property and if its pointing to directory where you have very less space, Please change it to some other directory which have more space.

While running tasks cotainers create blocks which gets store in yarn.nodemanger.log-dirs location, if its not enough to store the blocks container starts to fail.

Comment: Select * from table_1 cluster by col -- I used this at the end of each select in dataframes and then store the dataframes in temp tables and apply the joins there, and it worked perfectly.